# TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable

Tags: python, vba, email, outlook

I'm using win32.client and trying to manipulate email body text.

This was working today but I think when testing I might have broken Outlook! When I try to call an index of a _Folders object, I get a type error that it is uncallable.

I use indexes to get into my nested folders. This was working until tonight and I haven't changed any of the code.

```
import win32com.client
import urllib.parse
import webbrowser
from pyshorteners import Shortener

application = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = application.GetNamespace('MAPI')

# 6 is the number for the main inbox
inbox_folder = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

# had to create multiple objects of subfolders to get to specific directory
inbox = inbox_folder.Folders
mobile_folder = inbox(3)
mobile_folder_directory = mobile_folder.Folders
mobile_script_folder = mobile_folder_directory(2)

# using Items method to parse specific email files within the folder
messages = inbox_folder.Items
```

I get this error:

> File "mail1.py", line 10, in  mobile_folder = inbox_folders(3) TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable

I was messing around with other code trying to monitor my inbox for new mail.

I ran some of this code in another file with some modifications to match my inboxes

```
import ctypes # for the VM_QUIT to stop PumpMessage()
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
import sys


# outlook config
SHARED_MAILBOX = "Your Mailbox Name"

# get the outlook instance and inbox folder
session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session
user = session.CreateRecipient(SHARED_MAILBOX)
shared_inbox = session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(user, 6).Items  # 6 is Inbox


class HandlerClass(object):

    def OnItemAdd(self, item):
        print("New item added in shared mailbox")
        if item.Class == 43:
            print("The item is an email!")


outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents(shared_inbox, HandlerClass)


def main():
    print("Starting up Outlook watcher")
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        status = main()
        sys.exit(status)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminating program..")
        ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0)
        sys.exit()
```

My suspicion is that it changed something with Outlook versions.

I also got something saying that a MAPIFolder object isn't callable. My research was showing this is an old, unsupported Outlook protocol.

Here's more data when I try to index my folders:

```
>>> inbox_folder
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library.MAPIFolder instance at 0x12191504>
>>> inbox = inbox_folder.Folders
>>> inbox
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._Folders instance at 0x46668848>
>>> inbox(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share the details of the error?

Comment: Hey @TsTeaTime, sorry first time on here really. I get a 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail1.py", line 10, in <module>
    mobile_folder = inbox_folders(3)
TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable

Comment: Hi, no worries. just want to make sure that you get a helpful answer from someone. Try editing your question and adding this info into the original information.

Comment: @TsTeaTime I appreciate it! I've added more info

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what broke it, but it turns out that searching folders by index wasn't working anymore.

The solution was now searching by folder name:

```
inbox_folder = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

# had to create multiple objects of subfolders to get to specific directory
inbox = inbox_folder.Folders
mobile_folder = inbox["Mobile"]
mobile_script_folder = mobile_folder.Folders["Mobile_4_4_Alpha"]
```

not sure why it fixed it but it did. yay!

Answer (score 0):

don't know why but delete this file work in my case.

```
C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\[python version]\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6.py
```

credit: https://blog.csdn.net/ericatardicaca/article/details/90721909