# TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable with win32com

Tags: python, outlook, typeerror, win32com

The only information I've found regarding my issue are from other StackOverflow questions that don't actually resolve my issue.

[TypeError: '_Folders' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980099/typeerror-folders-object-is-not-callable)

[Using Outlook via win32com, suddenly getting runtime error '_Folders' object is not callable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101334/using-outlook-via-win32com-suddenly-getting-runtime-error-folders-object-is)

Script has been working perfectly for the past 3 months, but has suddenly stopped working today (no changes were made between it working yesterday, and being broken today)

What confuses me the most is that I have tried the exact same script on another PC and it still works perfectly fine.
(both transferring the problem .py file and also rewriting the code to a new script file)

**Given the above, I assume the error is my PC specific, however I have no idea what it could be.**

For reference, my Outlook has two accounts linked to it and I need to access the second account, so DefaultFolder() will not work

```
import win32com.client

mailbox = ['Address', 'Inbox']

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Returns the same error
inbox = namespace.Folders(mailbox[0]).Folders(mailbox[1])
inbox = namespace.Folders('Address').Folders('Inbox')
inbox = namespace.Folders('Address')

inbox = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders('Address')
inbox = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders('Address').Folders('Inbox')

# Error
>>> File c:\...\script.py, line 15, in <module>
>>>    inbox = namespace.Folders('Address').Folders('Inbox')
>>> TyperError: '_Folders' object is not callable
```

Not sure if this confirms anything, however another test I did is as follows:

```
# Deliberately misspell .Folders()
inbox = namespace.folders('Address').Folders('Inbox')

# Error
>>> File c:\...\script.py, line 15, in <module>
>>>    inbox = namespace.folders('Address').Folders('Inbox')
>>> AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._NameSpace instance at 0x2380896888784>' 
>>>  object has no attribute 'folders'. Did you mean: 'Folders'?


# Deliberately misspell .Folders()
inbox = namespace.Folder('Address').Folders('Inbox')

# Error
>>> File c:\...\script.py, line 15, in <module>
>>>    inbox = namespace.Folder('Address').Folders('Inbox')
>>> AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._NameSpace instance at 0x2380896888784>' 
>>>  object has no attribute 'Folder'. Did you mean: 'Folders'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking one of the original questions above, I have learnt more about the vagueries of `win32com.client`. The OP has been snagged by the late-vs-early binding gotcha in `win32com.client.Dispatch()`.

*The quickest short-term fix is to change the object creation line to:*

```
outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
```

Another quick, but ultimately less durable fix is to locate the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` directory and delete the `gen_py` folder.

Yet another is to replace `()` with `[]` when indexing, eg:

```
inbox = namespace.Folders['Address'].Folders['Inbox']
```

However, my preference for a durable solution would be to change the object creation line to:

```
outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
```

and change `Folders()` to `Folders[]`.

**Why do I have to do this when my code was working just fine previously?**

The answer to this is that you are calling `win32com.client.Dispatch()` and letting `win32com` decide *at runtime* whether to use Early or Late binding to the COM object you are creating. If you know you want Early binding, use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` and if you know you want Late binding, use `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch()`. *If you don't choose, `win32com` will, and may not always make the same choice*.

When you use `win32com.client.Dispatch()`, you are asking `win32com` to choose which binding you will get, and `win32com` will choose Early binding whenever it can. It looks for the generated Python wrapper files for your object on the filesystem: it if finds them, then you get Early binding.

If when you first wrote your code, the Python wrappers were not available, then you would get Late binding. In terms of code this means you can use `()` indexing and case-**IN**sensitive method names.

All is working fine until (maybe without your knowing) some other Python code calls `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` which generates the wrapper files for your object. The next time your code runs (and calls `Dispatch()`) `win32com` will find the wrapper files and switch to Early binding. This is more restrictive and `()` indexing will no longer work (as the OP has found), and method names are now case-sensitive. On the plus side you now have access to `win32com.client.constants` which allows you to use any enums associated with your object (eg `olMail` for an Mail Object Class rather than the less obvious number 43).

This snippet shows the difference:

```
import win32com.client as wc

bEarly = True
addr = 'john.doe@somewhere.com'
fldr = None

if bEarly:
    print('Using Early Binding')
    outlook = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application') 
    ns = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI') 
    fldrs = ns.Folders
    print(type(fldrs))
    fldr = fldrs[addr]
else:
    print('Using Late Binding')
    outlook = wc.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    ns = outlook.gEtNaMeSpAcE('MAPI')
    fldrs = ns.fOLdErS
    print(type(fldrs))
    fldr = fldrs(addr)

print(fldr.Name)
```

With `bEarly=False`, Late binding is enforced and the Folders object is of type `<class 'win32com.client.dynamic.CDispatch'>`. I *believe* this class has the `__call__` method implemented, which directs any method calls without names (eg `obj()`) to that object's *default* method, which for many Office collection objects is `Item()`. Hence `Folders(addr)` is translated to `Folders.Item(addr)`.

With `bEarly=True`, Early binding uses the Python wrappers to define a new class type: in this case the rather cryptic `<class 'win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6._Folders._Folders'>`. This class has all the methods of the object (you can look in the .py file in the `gen_py` folder for that CLSID). This wrapper does not provide a default interface, so no `()`. Instead, the wrapper knows this object is a collection so can be indexed in the usual Python way with `[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I ran it with both `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch` and `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch` and they both worked. So in an attempt to find the original problem I changed the `(mailbox[0])` to `[mailbox[0]]` and it only threw the error with `()`. I find this weird considering I know I tried this prior to asking the question to no avail, however as you mentioned it may be because I specifically called `gencache.EnsureDispatch` which may have generated the wrapper files then. **On a side note: When would I want to use `gencache` vs `dynamic`?**

Comment: @Shock Basically using `dynamic` or `gencache` returns you different Python types, so the methods may not be the same on each. My preference is to always use `gencache`, because 1) it avoids the kind of inconsistencies you have encountered, 2) it is more efficient (though this may only be a factor in certain circumstances), 3) the generated python wrappers can be inspected to see what methods/properties an object provides, 4) you are constrained to use the correct case in names (which is a good thing in my mind), and 5) by using `win32com.client.constants` you get the enums from the object.

Comment: @Shock. I would probably only use `dynamic` in situations where I am writing code that may not have complete access to the file system (for some reason).